# Updating multiple rows in PGSQL to the same value

Tags: postgresql, psql

I apologize if this has been asked before, but I googled and could not come up with a good search to find out.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
col_a, col_b
    a,     1,
    a,     2,
    a,     3,
    b,     1,
    b,     2,
    c,     1,
```

I need to update the values in col_a using a function that generates a random code value, but all values of 'a' need to update to the same value, same for 'b' etc. Is there a systematic way to do this, other than:

```
UPDATE tbl SET col_a = make_code() WHERE col_a = 'a';
UPDATE tbl SET col_a = make_code() WHERE col_a = 'b'; ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `make_code()` truly work like `random()`, multiple `update` statements does not guarantee the same code per `update` statements.

You need to calculate a code before the real update takes place (for each `distinct` original code). You can do it with a sub-query, or (more readable with) a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html):

```
with codes as (
  select distinct on (col_a)
         col_a original_code,
         make_code() generated_code
  from   tbl
)
update tbl
set    col_a = generated_code
from   codes
where  col_a = original_code;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3b876/3)

Comment: You are absolutely correct and this works perfectly, that didn't occur to me in my example. Thank you!